# How to create an icon for a Safari Mobile website on Springboard?

Tags: php, ios, mobile-safari

How do I specify an icon for a bookmark on Springboard when a user adds it to their home screen? I added a favicon, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the information about this is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Add the icon file with the name `touch-icon-iphone.png` to the root of your server, then add this tag to the head section of your web page:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

For more information about the resolution and sizes check the above link (I don't want to copy/page a whole page of documentation here).